# How do I limit what characters can be typed

Tags: vba, visual-studio, text, textbox

I want to make sure that only letters can be typed into this `TextBox`. I do not want characters like `£`, `$` or even numbers being typed in. I know how to limit the amount of characters with `MaxLength`, but not what characters can be typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `VBA` you can analyze what is entered in the keypress event. You can do this in `VB.NET` also, it will just be a bit different.

```
Private Sub Text4_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'This will allow only numaric values in the Text4 text box.
    If KeyAscii = 8 Then Exit Sub
    If Chr(KeyAscii) < "0" Or Chr(KeyAscii) > "9" Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also look at the keys in the `KeyDown` event also.  If you get a key you don't want, set the `KeyCode` to `0` and `Exit Sub` or what you want.

```
Private Sub Text4_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        KeyCode = 0
        DataGrid1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

You will look at the decimal number for the characters represented here.
http://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php

Comment: Thanks, by the way, is that for the Text2 text box, or Text4?

Comment: Ha, it is for text box 4. That was one of those copy paste things.  And this if for VBA by the way. You have that tag so i'm not sure what you need.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer, but I've found a way myself since I only need one character in the TextBox at a time. I just check if it has anything in it, and if it does, then it will check if it is a letter. Thanks anyways! It will be the accepted answer.

Comment: @DavidWheatley there **is** a difference between them, just a reminder. It does **matter** what you use because of the syntax, you tagged `VB.Net` and `VBA` which are different.

Comment: @DavidWheatley `VBA` is used for macros on Office documents, it does not have access to VB.NET features.

Answer (score 1):

To limit what the user can key in you can handle the `KeyPress` event of the `textbox`.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 97 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 122) Or (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 65 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 90)) Then
            e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can limit what the user enter's by adding a string of allowed characters. If it's not allowed, the event is not handled.

```
If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
    Dim allowedChars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    If Not allowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString.ToLower) Then
        e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End If
```

Comment: `Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar)` may also be useful.

Comment: I agree, there are more than a few way's.